# No LVN_GETINFOTIP notifications in a LVS_REPORT Listview of text cells

Tags: c, winapi

I have a listview of texts and have total control over it, works like a dream.

Except I don't get any LVN_GETINFOTIP notifications by WM_NOTIFY. I get every other notifications message but not LVN_GETINFOTIP.

I have spent some time been Googling and trying whatever I can find. Some sites say that from Vista it works different but not what different. I don’t care if it works before Win10 (can live with it) and not at all if it works before Win7.

I really wonder what prevents the LVN_GETINFOTIP messages?

```
switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
    {
    case LVN_GETINFOTIP:


CreateListView(
    0, 
    LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_INFOTIP | LVS_EX_LABELTIP, 
    0, 
    3 * TAB_HIGHT, 
    OwnWindowWidth, 
    OwnWindowHight - (OBJ_WINDOW_HIGHT + (3 * TAB_HIGHT)), 
    hWnd, 
    (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_LISTVIEW, 
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE));

static HWND CreateListView(
    DWORD dwAddStyle, 
    DWORD dwAddExtendedListViewStyle, 
    int X, 
    int Y, 
    int nWidth, 
    int nHeight, 
    HWND hWndParent, 
    HMENU IdListWiew, 
    HINSTANCE hInst)
{
    HWND hWndListView;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;

    memset(&icex, 0, sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX));

    // Ensure that the common control DLL is loaded. 

    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    // Create the list-view window in report view with label 
    // editing enabled.

    hWndListView = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES, WC_LISTVIEW, L"",
        WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WM_NOTIFY | dwAddStyle,
        X, Y, nWidth, nHeight,
        hWndParent, IdListWiew, hInst, NULL);
    if (hWndListView == NULL)
        return NULL;
    ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hWndListView, dwAddExtendedListViewStyle);

    return hWndListView;
}
```

Comment: `WM_NOTIFY` this is not window style.

Comment: I know for a fact that `LVN_GETINFOTIP` works, because I use it in my own ListView. Do you have ComCtrl32 v6 enabled? And why are you passing the extended styles to `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle()` instead of to `CreatewindowEx()` directly? You should be using `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle()` when *changing* styles, because ListView extended styles cannot be changed with `SetWindowLong/Ptr()`

Comment: The WM_NOTIFY is no style and makes no difference removing it, why it is there I don't know. Tried to make this work a few years ago and gave up.

Comment: I think a good path might be the issue of  ComCtrl32 v6 enabled?

The InitCommonControlsEx(&icex); makes no difference and looks to be loaded by the initiation. Putting more classes in the  icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES; makes no difference. 

I have no Manifest written in XML for it, is it really necessary?

My initiations are:
 #define _WIN32_WINDOWS _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
 #define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
 #define WINVER _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 // Minimum support
 #define _WIN32_IE 0x0600
 #pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <CommCtrl.h>

Comment: I think the initiation of the ComCtrl32 v6 is really the key factor. (The odd thing is that TVN_GETINFOTIP works fine no problem. How did you initiate it?

Comment: The WM_NOTIFY is no style but must be set as a Style (0x004E) in the CreateWindowEx DWORD dwStyle parameter in order to make the LVIS_SELECTED state in a LVM_SETITEMSTATE message to make the message CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT: After an item is drawn to be sent to WM_NOTIFY. Else nothing happens. I can't tell why and I can't see any  corresponding style related to 0x004E. Amazing but obviously a fact. Else I can't see selected lines in the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error myself!

The sample code for ListViews I once used hides the first column and so I can't get any TVN_GETINFOTIP because there is nothing to hover (Width of column 0 was 0). I managed to find this by reduction of code in a test program and read it real carefully. A bit embarrassed I asked. But this is coding life.

I have now a very compact sample code 160lines of a report ListView if it comes to use. (I rather this question to be removed).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define IDC_MAIN_LISTVIEW       100
#define MAIN_LISTFIELDS 9
#define MAIN_LISTLINES 78
int     iMainFieldsWidth[MAIN_LISTFIELDS] = { 50, 60, 78, 70,  100, 50, 50, 121, 112 };
WORD    wMainFieldsAlign[MAIN_LISTFIELDS] = { LVCFMT_RIGHT,LVCFMT_LEFT, LVCFMT_LEFT,LVCFMT_LEFT,LVCFMT_LEFT, LVCFMT_RIGHT, LVCFMT_RIGHT, LVCFMT_LEFT, LVCFMT_LEFT };
WCHAR   *pMainFieldsHeader[MAIN_LISTFIELDS] = { L"zero",L"one",L"Two",L"Three",L"Four",L"five",L"six",L"seven",L"eight" };
LRESULT WINAPI  MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    CREATESTRUCT MainWindowCreateStruct;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    MSG msg;
    HWND hWnd;
    if (!hPrevInstance)
    {
        wc.lpszClassName = L"AppClass";
        wc.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
        wc.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, L"1");
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER + 1);
        wc.lpszMenuName = L"AppMenu";
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = 0;

        RegisterClass(&wc);
    }

    memset(&MainWindowCreateStruct, 0, sizeof(CREATESTRUCT));
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES, L"AppClass",
        L"LvTest",
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        &MainWindowCreateStruct
    );

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // Main message loop: 
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT WINAPI  MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
            // Create the list-view window in report view with label 
            // editing enabled.

            HWND hLvWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES, WC_LISTVIEW, L"",
                WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
                0, 0, 1000, 500,
                hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_LISTVIEW, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);
            if (hLvWnd == NULL)
                return 0;
            ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hLvWnd, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_INFOTIP | LVS_EX_LABELTIP);

            ListView_DeleteAllItems(hLvWnd);
            {
            LVCOLUMN lvc;
            int iCol = 0;

            memset(&lvc, 0, sizeof(LVCOLUMN));

            while (ListView_DeleteColumn(hLvWnd, 0)); // Nonvisual left column

                                                      // Initialize the LVCOLUMN structure.
                                                      // The mask specifies that the format, width, text, and
                                                      // subitem members of the structure are valid. 

            lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
            // Add the columns. 
            for (iCol = 0; iCol < MAIN_LISTFIELDS; iCol++)
                {
                lvc.iSubItem = iCol;
                lvc.pszText = pMainFieldsHeader[iCol];
                lvc.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
                lvc.iImage = 0;
                lvc.iOrder = 0;
                lvc.cx = iMainFieldsWidth[iCol];     // width of column in pixels
                lvc.fmt = wMainFieldsAlign[iCol];  // alignment of column

                if (ListView_InsertColumn(hLvWnd, lvc.iSubItem, &lvc) == -1)
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            {
            LVITEM lvI;
            DWORD index = 0;

            memset(&lvI, 0, sizeof(LVITEM));

            // Some code to create the list-view control.
            // Initialize LVITEM members that are common to all
            // items. 
            lvI.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_STATE | LVIF_INDENT;
            lvI.state = 0;
            lvI.stateMask = 0;

            // Initialize LVITEM members that are different for each item. 
            for (index = 0; index < MAIN_LISTLINES; index++)
                {
                lvI.iItem = index;
                lvI.iImage = 0; // Icon
                lvI.iIndent = 0;
                lvI.iSubItem = 0;
                //      lvI.lParam = (LPARAM) &rgPetInfo[index];
                lvI.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK; // sends an
                                                  // LVN_GETDISPINFO
                                                  // message.                                     
                if (ListView_InsertItem(hLvWnd, &lvI) == -1)
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
            switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
                {
                case LVN_GETINFOTIP:
                    if (lParam)
                        { // This is only working it looks, or actually the LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_INFOTIP  | LVS_EX_LABELTIP of the CreateWindowEx isn't, would be nice to have
                        LPNMLVGETINFOTIP pGetInfoTip = (LPNMLVGETINFOTIP)lParam;
                        wcscpy(pGetInfoTip->pszText, L"This is an InfoTip Text\nand it takes newlines", pGetInfoTip->cchTextMax);
                        }
                    break;
                case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
                    if (lParam)
                        {
                        NMLVDISPINFO *plvdi = ((NMLVDISPINFO *)lParam);
                        if ((plvdi->hdr.hwndFrom == GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_MAIN_LISTVIEW)) && (plvdi->item.iSubItem<MAIN_LISTFIELDS) && plvdi->item.cchTextMax)
                            wcsncpy(plvdi->item.pszText, pMainFieldsHeader[plvdi->item.iSubItem], plvdi->item.cchTextMax);
                        }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            break;
        default:
            return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works only in first column. I tried the other columns, don't work. Odd (old) implementation of ListView by MS? The MS ListView implementations is odd in other ways. Having 20 000 lines a Win10 knees in a MS ListView (C-code, but it is the shell that is slow) while in Android Java ListViews are as quick any length of the list (only asking for the lines in view). Odd the mobile ARM Android phone has better app performance than a Win10 i5? What I understand it is possible to write own code for the MS ListView but that is a hazzel to do. But most likely something that has to be done at the end.